# Why are some methods in class ThreadLocalRandom not in class Random?

Tags: java, random

The [ThreadLocalRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) class was introduced in jdk 1.7. It has some convenient methods in addition to those already in java.util.Random, such as `nextInt(least, bound)` and `nextLong(n)`. Is there any reason these weren't added to java.util.Random? After all, it's not as if they didn't want to touch class Random, as they had added a whole load of new methods to it in Java 8.

I'm looking for any objective technical reasons (not opinions).

Comment: Maybe there were problems with implementing these methods in a cryptographically strong way for SecureRandom. That would seem like the most reasonable assumption.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are technical reasons for that. Those methods could be added already in 1.7. I guess `java.util.Random` is semi deprecated in favor of `ThreadLocalRandom` & `SecureRandom` due to excessive synchronization - just like Hashtable & Vector. New stream methods in Java8 were added to `java.util.Random` only because it is the super class for other two RNGs, there is no separate interface like java.util.Collection.

Comment: Is there any evidence that `Random` and/or `SecureRandom` may be deprecated like you say or is that your opinion?